# cmd doesn't work after remove the path

Tags: cmd

in wrong i remove the path from my computer, now the path is empty , i don't have restore point or backup to get the path, now when i type help in cmd i got `not a command`, would you tell me how can i got the path? or what i have to input into the path? thank you very much

Comment: Are you saying you accidentally deleted a directory (folder) and want to know how to get it back?  If so, it's off-topic here, but we might be able to help or point to to the appropriate forum.  Windows, Linux, or other OS?  And did you delete it in code, or did you simply delete the folder in the normal Windows (Linux) UI?  (In which case, look in the Recycle Bin.)

Comment: no not on code , i want to add a path to the path variable and in wrong i delete alll the oldest paht :( :(, now i got problems in connecting my mobile device to my computer, and i need to get that path ASAP , becuase my graduation project on next sunday :(

Comment: AHHH Sorry, my misunderstanding.  You're talking about THIS path: http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml  right?  Or this one?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: yes :( :( that one, right click on computer ,advance ,environment, system vairalbles , path :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [default values on Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: and do u know, after install android, what is the added value to path?

Comment: what does android have anything to do with windows path?

Comment: you told me `%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`and in the link i found this `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem` is it the same? and which one i have to write ?

Comment: i don't know if there is anything about android, i am just asking because i have probles in install my phone on my compe, i suggest that problesm comes from path, am i right?

Comment: they should both be OK as long as you add new ones with a `;`